# how can i use ruby and twitter tweet from text file

Tags: ruby, file, twitter, readfile, tweets

I'm trying to tweet from a text file without getting the extra symbols.

My tweets looks like:
["This is a sample of my tweet on twitter"\n] << it includes the symbols and the extra "n".

What I'm trying to get is:
This is a sample of what I want my tweet to look like.  << no extra symbols.

My code:

```
def tweet
  file = File.open("tweets_from.txt","r")
  read = file.readlines.sample(1)
  client.update("#{read}").text
end

tweet
```

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is enough to just change

```
read = file.readlines.sample(1)
```

to this:

```
read = file.readlines.sample.chomp
```

More about this method (and many other!) here: [Ruby String docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/String.html#method-i-chomp)

Answer (score 1):

```
read = file.readlines.map(&:chomp).sample
client.update(read).text
```

Comment: Here you do _chomp_ on whole array while it isn't necessary.